# How to get count of satellites in iOS?

Tags: ios, core-location

I can not find out how to get count of satellites that device has got using CoreLocation. In my Android app I have information like this, and I'd like to have it in my iOS app.
Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand why Apple restricts many basic functionalities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible using any publicly available iOS API.

Check the `CLLocation` class [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html) for a list of attributes you can query, for example `horizontalAccuracy` and `verticalAccuracy` may be of some use to you.

Answer (score 5):

Andy is correct.  The only thing I would add is you can assume there are at least 4 satellites if the verticalAccuracy is > 0.  You probably have 5 or more if the horizontalAccuracy is within 0-60m.  You probably have only 3 if the horizontalAccuracy is 60-300m and verticalAccuracy is < 0.  And finally you probably have < 3 satellites if the horizontalAccuracy > 300m and vertical < 0.  Those are roughly what it takes for various levels of accuracy.  I don't think CL will report < 500m accuracy on WiFi or Cell only locations.